# Manually erroring out a ReadableStream or TransformStream causes the error to be logged as an uncaught error

Tags: javascript, whatwg-streams-api

When calling [ReadableStreamDefaultController.error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultController/error) or `TransformStreamDefaultController.error` with an Error object to manually error out a stream, the error is logged in the browser console, at the site of invocation, as an uncaught error, as if the `.error()` method itself was re-throwing the error it was fed.

The following short snippet with a ReadableStream source and WritableStream destination showcases the issue, however, it seems the stackoverflow snippet console fails to log the error (check the browser console, on Chrome 80):

```js
let sourceController;
let source = new ReadableStream({
    start: (controller) => {
        sourceController = controller;
    }
});

let destination = new WritableStream({
    start: () => {
     // ...
    },
    abort: (reason) => {
     console.log("aborted:");
        console.log(reason);
    }
});

source.pipeTo(destination);
window.setTimeout(() => sourceController.error(new Error("wut?")), 1000);
//                                       ^^^^^
//                                       js:30 Uncaught (in promise) Error: wut?
```

Judging by the error message, this may be a rejected promise somewhere, but I have no idea where. Strangely, trying to observe this uncaught error using the following listener has no effect either:

```
window.onerror = (e) => console.error(e); // Never gets called
```

I would've thought defining the `abort` method on the destination WritableStream marks that the stream is enabled with error handling, yet the error is still logged as an uncaught error (strangely, the `abort` method *is* called at the same time).

To me it seems this error is completely harmless, but it sure is annoying.

**How do I get rid of it?** Adding a `try ... catch` around the thing doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is originating from the Promise returned by the `pipeTo` call, because erroring out the stream will *reject* this Promise. The solution is to add the missing catch clause:

```js
source.pipeTo(destination).catch(err => ...)
```

Or, in an `async` execution context:

```js
try {
    await source.pipeTo(destination);
} catch (err) {
    ...
}
```

This is explained in the [WHATWG Streams spec](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#rs-pipe-to):

> An error in the source readable stream will abort the destination writable stream, unless preventAbort is truthy. **The returned promise will be rejected** with the source’s error, or with any error that occurs during aborting the destination.